# How to store the current location Latitude and Longitude in NSString IOS7

Tags: ios, google-maps, nsstring, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hi in my application I'm fetching the the current location using Google IOS SDK know i want to store the current location Longitude and Latitude NSString please tell me how to do it.

My current location fetching code.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
      GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:17.0];
      [googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

 }
```

I'm using the above code to get the current location please tell how to store the latitude and langitude in NSString .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {

 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                    longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                         zoom:17.0];
  [googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

    NSString *getcurrlong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *getcurrlat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];


}
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateTo newLocation: CLLocation, from oldLocation: CLLocation) {
print("didUpdateToLocation: \(newLocation)")
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
let currentLocation: CLLocation? = newLocation
if currentLocation != nil {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(with: newLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 17.0)
    googleMapView.animate(to: camera)
    var getcurrlong = String(format: "%.8f", currentLocation?.coordinate?.longitude)
    var getcurrlat = String(format: "%.8f", currentLocation?.coordinate?.latitude)
}
}
```

Comment: In swift 3 i have used didUpdateLocations instead of  didUpdateToLocation

Comment: Will you please tell me when will this method get called, i.e while entering into selected page or when user moved to another location?

Comment: entering into selected page in here called

Comment: its giving error in swift 3 , Cannot override 'locationmanager' which has been marked unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

Comment: in this place use `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {`

Comment: yes i have used that method but here the problem is that method is calling more that 4 times , My requirement is i have to get the location first then i have to call API